# Facebook thumbnail bigger size

Tags: php, facebook, thumbnails

I'm using this to get thumbnail image:
https://graph.facebook.com/806640129377133/picture

But this outputs image sized 160 x 160px and I need at least 640 x 360 px. I tried several methods (like this: https://graph.facebook.com/806640129377133/picture?type=large) but nothing works.  How can I get bigger thumbnail?

Answer (score 2):

The method luschn mentioned is the normal one to ask for pictures with specific dimensions; however here it doesn’t seem to work, specifying larger values for width/height still gives only the 160×160 version.

If you [look at the `format` field](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=806640129377133%3Ffields%3Dformat&version=v2.1) however, it shows something like this,

```
  "format": [
    {
      "embed_html": "<iframe src=…></iframe>", 
      "filter": "130x130", 
      "height": 130, 
      "picture": "…", 
      "width": 130
    }, 
    {
      "embed_html": "<iframe src=…></iframe>", 
      "filter": "native", 
      "height": 400, 
      "picture": "…", 
      "width": 400
    }
  ],
```

So a bigger version of the picture is available, in this case sized 400×400.

Although it even mentions a `filter` property in there, I have not yet found a way to get it to spit out the large picture only – but you could loop through this and see which one has the largest width/height yourself.

And if you make that call [?fields=format{picture,width,height}](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=806640129377133%3Ffields%3Dformat%7Bpicture%2Cwidth%2Cheight%7D&version=v2.1), you will get only the `picture`, `width` and `height` properties (if you want to keep the footprint small and avoid requesting unnecessary data).

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! Works perfectly! Spent half a day looking for this solution! Thanks @CBroe!

Answer (score 0):

This is how to get the picture in the desired resolution:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/[Graph-ID]/picture?width=121&height=100
```

It may be a bit bigger, but it will have the set width and height parameters as minimum values.

If it does not work, the image is probably not uploaded in a resolution that is big enough. This works great for profile pictures of profiles (avatars), but in that case it is a video and i doubt that you will get a larger one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @CBroe for the original solution.

Here is the simplest way to get the highest resolution thumbnail of a facebook video.

```
$request_url ="https://graph.facebook.com/{VIDEO_ID}/?fields=format{picture,width,height}";

$requests = file_get_contents($request_url);

$fb_response = json_decode($requests);

echo end($fb_response->format)->picture; //highest resolution image available
```

Spent half a day looking for this! Hope I'm saving your time! :D